# Linux Compiling opencv python error: ImportError: libjasper.so.1

Tags: python, linux, opencv, linker

I have built opencv from source, and have tried to create simple program in python, but run into this error in the terminal

```
 line 3, in <module>
 import cv2
 ImportError: libjasper.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In addition, when trying to compile in c++, i get this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libjasper.so.1, needed by 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1.0, not found (try using -
rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue please?

Comment: On Ubuntu and CentOS, you should be able to install this by package (e.g., libjasper-dev on Ubuntu).  What OS are you trying this on?

Comment: I am using arch linux

Comment: It looks like there is a [version](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/jasper/) of libjasper for Arch that should work.  Did you build libjasper from source by chance?  If so, then you just need to add to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH the location of libjasper.so.1.  Alternatively, you can build jasper from source when building OpenCV (the BUILD_JASPER option), and it will be linked statically.

Comment: i just installed the package from aur, i did not set any paths though

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Arch Linux too and faced the same issue, it's related to the way opencv links to the lib.

If you do `ls -lah /usr/lib | grep libjasper` it should output something like

`-rw-r--r--   1 root root  569K nov 21 16:59 libjasper.a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    18 nov 21 16:59 libjasper.so -> libjasper.so.4.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    18 nov 21 16:59 libjasper.so.4 -> libjasper.so.4.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  342K nov 21 16:59 libjasper.so.4.0.0`

Which is not wrong by itself, libjasper is installed, the problem is related to the version, for some reason, when opencv asks for the lib it does with version `libjasper.so.x`, it should ask for it like `libjasper.so` which in turn points to `libjasper.so.4`, which point to... and so on.

I solved the issue creating a symlink to the lib
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libjasper.so /usr/lib/libjasper.so.1`

Although this is not the best way to this (probably better compiling libjasper by hand) it is probably the fastest, and it works.

You can see the results trying to run the script again.